# Different number of samples affecting naive Bayes

Tags: sampling, sample-size, naive-bayes, weka

I am trying to build a model of 7 classes text documents.

However, i do not have equal number of samples for each class. I can have close to about 10k documents for class A but only about 100 samples for class E. How is it possible that I can improve my model. I am achieving about 80% accuracy currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paper "[Tackling the Poor Assumptions of Naive Bayes Text Classifiers](http://people.csail.mit.edu/~jrennie/papers/icml03-nb.pdf)" there are given some modifications of the original algorithm that correct the bias in the estimation of the probabilities.

Hope that helps

Comment: hi do you have the code implementation for this algorithm or where can i find it?

Comment: I remember it is implemented in a Perl module available in cpan. Otherwise i do not know any other. Nevertheless, if you have an implementation of nb, you can just add the correction for skew classes to your code

Answer (score 0):

According to Jumpa paper, I have found a solution which implements the complement naive Bayes classifier in weka.

This is the url to the download.

http://weka.sourceforge.net/packageMetaData/complementNaiveBayes/index.html